# Salesforce Rest API (upsert): System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: EXCEEDED_MAX_SIZE_REQUEST: size of unauthenticated request is too large

Tags: salesforce

I am facing this issue intermittently but not for every request. Can you please help me on this. Below is my code for sending request to salesforce rest api:

```
loginResult = _sfCachingManager.GetLoginResult();
if (_loginResult != null && _loginResult.userInfo != null)
{     
  _sforceService.Url = _loginResult.serverUrl;
  _sforceService.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader();
  _sforceService.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = _loginResult.sessionId;
  Account account = _sfModelMapping.AccountMapping(agency);
  UpsertResult[] result = _sforceService.upsert("Agency_ID__c", new sObject[] { account });
```

Some times, when I tried to send the request it generates exception as :

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: EXCEEDED_MAX_SIZE_REQUEST: size of unauthenticated request is too large at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You'll get this error sending requests to the login endpoint, it seems likely that you're sharing `_sforceService` across threads and when one of the decides it needs to login, it sets the Url to the login endpoint, and a concurrent request on another thread that thinks it sending a request to the authenticated endpoint actually ends up sending it to the login endpoint. Carefully review how you sharing the `_sforceService` across threads.

Comment: I have 50 requests constantly and out of them 48 were successfully only 2 got exception. Just for confirmation I have to complete one request at time or something else?

Comment: Yeah we have concurrent requests but we are fetching login result from salesforce only one time and storing it in cache and and for all the requests we are looking into cache not hitting salesforce every time.

Comment: Yeas you are right, one request hits different url i.e in default URL of salesforce service. How to get rid of this ?

Comment: Use a separate instance of the client stub for the login calls.